# NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[NSISLinearExpression _referenceView] On IOS 10.3.1 or lower

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I get the following error on iOS 10.3.1 or lower.

> NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[NSISLinearExpression _referenceView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000018a4f0

The error is given on my first screen and my application will not go further after the splash screen.

On iOS 11 or above my application works.

So if somebody has any idea how to solve this issue, please let me know.

This is the entire stack trace:

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   Reason: -[__NSCFData _referenceView]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6000001975c0 Native stack trace:   0   CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000114552b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171   1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00000001151eb141 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001145c2134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144d9840
>   ___forwarding___ + 1024  4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144d93b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x0000000112c8fb93 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>   nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:onBehalfOfLayoutGuide:]
>   + 749     6   Foundation                          0x0000000113cb506f -[NSLayoutAnchor nsli_lowerIntoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 376  7
>   Foundation                          0x0000000113b81c11
>   -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 99   8   Foundation                          0x0000000113b7b56e -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 121     9   UIKit                               0x0000000112c8ac71 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 454  10  Foundation                          0x0000000113b8182b -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] +
>   155   11  UIKit                               0x0000000112c8aa84
>   __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 604     12  UIKit                               0x0000000112c8a800 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>   _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 223     13  UIKit                               0x0000000112c89933 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>   _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 447  14  UIKit                               0x0000000112c7c499 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
>   _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 130  15  UIKit                               0x0000000112382909 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] +
>   209   16  UIKit                               0x0000000112382b43
>   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 779    17  UIKit                               0x0000000112375b96 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151  18  UIKit                               0x0000000112375a7d -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 828
>     19  UIKit                               0x0000000112385a0a
>   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1927     20  UIKit                               0x0000000112373cf8
>   -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 838    21  UIKit                               0x0000000112780cad -[UINavigationTransitionView
>   transition:fromView:toView:] + 616    22  UIKit
>   0x00000001124a9521 -[UINavigationController
>   _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3301     23  UIKit                               0x00000001124a9a03
>   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 843     24  UIKit                               0x00000001124aab41
>   -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58  25  UIKit                               0x000000011269c60c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231    26 
>   UIKit                               0x000000011238955b
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268     27  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111e18904 -[CALayer
>   layoutSublayers] + 146    28  QuartzCore
>   0x0000000111e0c526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE +
>   370   29  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111e0c3a0
>   _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24    30  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d9be92
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294   31  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111dc8130
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468    32  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111dc8b37
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144f8717
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23   34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144f8687
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391     35  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144dd038 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440   36  UIKit
>   0x00000001122c008f -[UIApplication _run] + 468    37  UIKit
>   0x00000001122c6134 UIApplicationMain + 159    38  ???
>   0x000000012c5f96e7 0x0 + 5039429351   39  ???
>   0x000000012c5f9443 0x0 + 5039428675

public partial class BaseAppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
    {

```
    public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        //implement Fabric/Crashlytics
        MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Setup.EnableCrashReporting(() =>
        {
            var crashlytics = Crashlytics.SharedInstance;
            crashlytics.DebugMode = false;
            Crashlytics.StartWithAPIKey("**************");
            Fabric.With(new NSObject[] { crashlytics });
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Setup.CaptureManagedInfo(e.ExceptionObject);
                MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Setup.CaptureStackFrames(e.ExceptionObject);
                MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Setup.ThrowExceptionAsNative(e.ExceptionObject);
            };
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Setup.CaptureManagedInfo(e.Exception);
                MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Setup.CaptureStackFrames(e.Exception);
                MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Setup.ThrowExceptionAsNative(e.Exception);
            };
        }, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(typeof(BaseAppDelegate).Module.Name));

        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var setup = new Setup(this, Window);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = new ColorUtil().PrimaryColor();
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.White;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;


        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                                                                  (granted, error) =>
                                                                  {
                                                                      if (granted)
                                                                          InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
                                                                  });
        }
        else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                   UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                   new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
        else
        {
            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
    {
        base.WillEnterForeground(application);

        var usageService = Mvx.Resolve<IUsageService>();
        usageService.AppResumed();
    }

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, string srcApp, NSObject annotation)
    {
        OpenUrl(url.ResourceSpecifier.Replace("//", "/"));

        return true;
    }

    public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
    {
        if (userActivity.ActivityType == "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb")
        {
            OpenUrl(userActivity.WebPageUrl.Path);
        }

        return true;
    }

    internal void OpenUrl(string path)
    {
        var normalized = Uri.UnescapeDataString(path);

        var linkingService = Mvx.Resolve<IUniversalLinkingService>();
        linkingService.OpenUrl(normalized);
    }

    #region Remote notifications

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        // Get current device token
        var value = deviceToken.Description;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            value = value.Trim('<').Trim('>').Replace(" ", "");
        }

        var accountBL = Mvx.Resolve<IAccountBL>();
        var settingsBL = Mvx.Resolve<ILocalSettingsBL>();

        if (accountBL == null || settingsBL == null)
            return;

        var oldToken = settingsBL.GetDeviceNotificationToken();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldToken) || oldToken != value)
        {
            accountBL.UpdateDeviceNotificationToken(value);
        }
    }

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        var accountBL = Mvx.Resolve<IAccountBL>();

        accountBL?.UpdateDeviceNotificationToken(null);
    }

    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        //base.ReceivedRemoteNotification(application, userInfo);

        if(userInfo["aps"] != null && userInfo["apps"] is NSDictionary apps && 
           apps["alert"] != null && apps["alertc"] is NSDictionary alert)
        {
            var pushNotification = new PushNotification();

            NSObject key;

            if(userInfo.TryGetValue(new NSString("ParticipantKey"), out key))
            {
                pushNotification.Type = PushNotificationType.Participant;
                pushNotification.Key = key.ToString();
            } else if (userInfo.TryGetValue(new NSString("OrganizerKey"), out key))
            {
                pushNotification.Type = PushNotificationType.Organizer;
                pushNotification.Key = key.ToString();
            }

            var pushNotificationService = Mvx.Resolve<PushNotificationService>();
            pushNotificationService.Open(pushNotification);

        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: set an exception breakpoint and see where exactly it stops

Comment: Already set the System.Exception BreakPoint but it will not fires when the application stops. I went debugging but when every thing is done it crashes and not on a line. But in iOS 11 or above it al works so there must be something that is wrong

Comment: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Would it be possible if you could post a bit more code around how your app starts? from a quick google, I see that `NSISLinearExpression` unrecognized selector errors can happen from not removing Observers from `NSNotificationCenter` but again will need more info to help debug this.

Comment: Iain Smith, I think you need the AppDelegate right. If you need more info can you just say what you need. So I can add it. The AppDelegate is added above.